# Can I apply for a Schengen visa in the USA as an Indian citizen with an H1-B extension in process?

Tags: usa, schengen, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, h1b-visas

My H1-B visa is expiring May 31st, 2018 and my H1-B extension is still in process.

At this point, can I still apply for a Schengen visa in the USA (France Consulate - SFO)? Will I be required to have a valid US visa when applying in the USA? In addition, do I need to have an H1B visa stamp on my passport as well?

Additional thoughts/questions :
1. What if I book my flight tickets to/from India to France (Paris) with no mention of the USA? Will it help my case?
2. Do I need to book an appointment for the Schengen visa at the SFO France consulate? Are walk-ins allowed?

Comment: This question has been asked several times. Use the search function

Comment: @TheZealot Yeah, I searched it and found conflicting answers. In particular, I would like to know the scenario about what if extension is in progress. In addition, I added two more questions for which I am looking answers for. I would appreciate any info on these.

Comment: @annunarcist I'm sorry you found conflicting answers. Unfortunately, asking the same question again doesn't resolve the conflict: whatever people say in answer to your question, those other conflicting answers still exist.